# Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 via proxy server

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, proxy, authentication

We're attempting to upgrade our Ubuntu 12.04 system to 14.04.
  Our internet connection for the Linux server goes via a proxy server that requires authentication.

From a putty session I've been able to start Firefox to browse the web without being prompted for username/password details, by setting the http_proxy and http_proxys environment variables to include a valid username and password.

However, when I try to use the same setting in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file, then I receive `407 Proxy Authentication Required` errors when using either `do-release-upgrade -c` or `apt-get` ...

I've read multiple discussions, but they all seem to point to this being the solution.  Does anybody have any idea if there's maybe something else I've missed that needs to be set?

Comment: it was just time to upgrade to 14.04, 12.04 was EOL for 3 years, 14.04 will be EOL too in few month

Comment: Aye, the plan is to migrate to 16.04 once we have 14.04 upgraded and stable.  We're using it to host a Nagios monitoring server.

Comment: No idea it is feasible for you  I would save yourself the cost of finding out what is wrong and pay for a new machine, put 18.04 on it and then set that up. 14.04 will be using systemd, not upstart, so you will probably need to do a lot more than just upgrading to get it all to work. Save yourself the trouble and skip 14.04 and 16.04. It will save money.

Comment: Cheers, that is something we're considering.  It was just I had a couple of spare days, so thought I'd give it a try.

Comment: Oh that's cool too. Nothing wrong with getting better at upgrading by upgrading ;-)

Comment: We cheated in the end and got our network guys to give us a direct link out to the internet from the host, so we're now on 14.04.5 LTS and starting to look at 16.04.5 :)  Thanks all